# Can we Use tablespace defined in one schema in another schema Of Oracle Database. If Yes, Please let me know the method

Tags: database, oracle

Consider that a tablespace is defined in one schema of oracle database. If i want too access the tablespace from another schema, Will it be working out or is there any grant permission to be declared. Please let know the method to access it.

Comment: A tablespace is **not** defined in a schema. It is a [database-level logical construct](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/logical.htm#CNCPT89026). Schema are granted quotas on tablespaces they need to store data in. What problem are you actually having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alexpoole said, tablespaces are database constructs in Oracle, not schema constructs. To grant a schema the ability to place objects in a tablespace, you must grant quota.

In the code below, we are granting user (schema) CQADM quotas on three tablespaces starting with "GP", one quota is 50 megabytes, one 1 gigabyte, and the last unlimited.

```
ALTER USER CQADM QUOTA 50M ON GP_FRACTURED_TS;
ALTER USER CQADM QUOTA 1G ON GP_TS;
ALTER USER CQADM QUOTA UNLIMITED ON GP_TS2;
```